# Voice disruption in two way communication in JAVA

Tags: java, lan, voice, livechat

I am developed a desktop voice chat application in **JAVAFX**. But in voice chatting, the voice is disrupted in a continues time interval. Anyone can help me to solve this issue. Code is provided below. Thanks in advance.

**My Server Machine Code**

```
public void startCalling()
    {
        inAudioThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buff = new byte[getBufferSize()];
                    Thread playSound = new Thread();
                    while((in.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1)
                    {
                        playAudio(buff,playSound);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        outAudioThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    serverSocket= new ServerSocket(9092);
                    serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                    socket      = serverSocket.accept();

                    inAudioThread.start();

                    AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
                    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
                    tLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                    tLine.open(format);
                    tLine.start();

                    byte buffer[] = new byte[getBufferSize()];

                    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    running = true;
                    try
                    {
                        while(running)
                        {
                            int count = tLine.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                            if (count > 0)
                            {
                                bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                            }
                        }
                        out.close();
                        bufferedOutputStream.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {

                    }
                }
                catch(IOException | LineUnavailableException e)
                {

                }
            }
        });

        outAudioThread.start();
    }
```

**Common Functions for server and Client**

```
public AudioFormat getAudioFormat()
    {
        AudioFormat.Encoding encoding   = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
        float   sampleRate              = 44100.0f;
        int     sampleSizeInBits        = 16;
        int     channels                = 2;
        int     frameSize               = (sampleSizeInBits / 8)* channels;
        boolean bigEndian               = true;

        return new AudioFormat(encoding, sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, frameSize,sampleRate,bigEndian);
    }
    public int getBufferSize()
    {
        return (int) getAudioFormat().getSampleRate()* getAudioFormat().getFrameSize();
    }
```

The Client Side code is same as the startCalling() function, but the lines

```
serverSocket= new ServerSocket(9092);
serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
socket      = serverSocket.accept();

replaced with **socket = new socket("192.168.8.100",9092);**.
```

Any one can help me to solve the voice disruption problem. Thanks again in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are not guaranteed to fill your buffer each time. In your **IN** thread you wrongly assume that each time you will read the entire buffer.

Instead you have to capture the number of bytes read like so:

```
while( (bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1 ) {
    //play audio from buffer *bytesRead* bytes at a time
}
```

You could use [IOUtils from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.htm) which has methods to read into buffer until the buffer is full (see **readFully** methods).

Please also note that in your OUT thread `out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();` and then writing to it in the `while(){}` loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Man...and your suggestion doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: No problem Man... please be more precise than 'it still doesn't work'. Perhaps your player has some requirements how the data should be fed to it (a specific amount of data at a time)? Could you share your `playAudio()` implementation?